# Is there a way to send php post requests without a web server?

Tags: php, xml, http

I was trying to send POST requests via Javascript but decided PHP would be more suitable. I was wondering if there is a way to send a request with PHP without using a web server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can run php from command line

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

you can create a php script and easily run it like a batch using:

c:\php\cli\php.exe script.php %1 %2 %3 %4